# expo notifications not popping up on screen

Tags: react-native, expo

I followed the same code for expo notifications and the sample is working fine. A pop up notification shows up on a predefined time.

Expo-Notification sample:
https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/notifications/

Problem is when the notification is coming from the expo server. The notification is shown on the notification list when you pull down the status bar of the phone but there is no pop up.

Expo Notification tool:
https://expo.io/notifications

Priority is already set to max and pop up shows fine when scheduled from the app but doesn't show up when it is coming from the expo server.

Comment: Have you found out?

Comment: a lot has changed in expo since I asked this question but I figured out that notifications won't show up in expo go. you have to install the app to your device and follow the configuration to add google config in expo so they can handle the sending notification service

Comment: @NatsE Can u guide how to do that please?

Comment: @NatsE I have the app running via expo dev-client on my physical device and i have the exact same problem with you. How did you go about fixing it, please?